# How to get the date value of an input?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date

I wonder how to get the date of the input and compare it with a list of objects.

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="date">
```

How do I get the value from the date and compare it with the date of my list of object? I mean after picking 23 as the day, there should some objects appear with the correct day and so on. I am not sure how to implement that.

Do anyone know how to implement such function in a good way?

EDIT: So far, I used (ngModelChange) to get the new date value.

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="date" (ngModelChange)="changedDate($event)>
```

Getting the value like this:

```
changedDate(e){
let date = e.target.value;
}
```

I wonder whether I can get a sub value for the date when not every field is filled but I think not since the validationMessage say the full date is required.

Comment: Would you show us how your "list of objects" looks like? Maybe that can help us understand "after picking 23 as the day, there should some objects appear with the correct day and so on"

Comment: For example ```[{ name: "carlo", date: "23.01.2012"}, { name: "carla", date: "20.10.1999}]```and the filter should only return the first object.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what what you expect to happen, what is happening, and what is not happening, and include what attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: is your date format going to be `dd.mm.yyyy`?

Comment: Yes, but for showing purpose you can use every format you like-

Comment: After you edited the question `validationMessage` whats this?

Comment: If you look up which events you can use on that input and console log it, you can see the validationMessage under target->validationMessage. ```changedDate(e){console.log(e)}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `YYYY-MM-DD` format for the dates which can directly be converted to Javascript `Date` objects. After these obejcts you can get date and compare the results.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgewbq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  dateArr = [{ name: 'carlo', date: '2012-01-23'}, { name: 'carla', date: '1999-10-20'}];

  changedDate(e) {
    const value = this.filterDate(new Date(e));

    if (value) {
      console.log('Object found', value)
    }
    else {
      console.log('Nothing found')
    }
  }

  filterDate(selectedDate: Date) {
    for(const d of this.dateArr) {
      const elemDate = new Date(d.date);
      if (elemDate.getDate() === selectedDate.getDate()) {
        return d;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this is great! I wonder if I could set a range like between 1999-01-01 and 2012-12-01 and then both objects appear in the console

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate it, if you could show an example of setting a range! But you dont have to

Comment: okey. are you fine with using two date input boxes for range and then finding the result?

Comment: As this question is answered can you please open new question so that it doesnt make confusion to any other user here. You can post the link here I ll answer it.

Comment: I will put the link here!

Comment: I can ask the next question in 90 minutes :/

Answer (score 3):

You can use ngModelChange event like this

```html
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="date" (ngModelChange)="date = $event">
```

also call a function like this

```html
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="date" (ngModelChange)="matchDate($event)">
```

Create that function and you will get  value on date change there you can get a date value with using function or just bind in the variable.

you can compare date with using momentjs

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) work. Pay attention for `[formControl]` directive and `valueChanges` observable of that formControl. You can access input data in your component with it.

Comment: Thank you, I will look it up!

Comment: Even if this is a good suggestion, the use of ReactiveForms is not needed to achieve a solution to this question.

Comment: Also you can look an implementation of some inputs here - https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples. Could give you some hints.

Comment: @maury844 true, but rf is Angular best practice since ngModel has been deprecated in v6. Also knowledge of ReactiveForms is essential, so why not learn it on such an easy example?

Answer (score 1):

if your date input is not part of a form and you need to update/check against values whenever the date changes you can do something like this:

```
<input type="email" [(value)]="date" (change)="dateChanged()">
```

if it is then you can use ngModelChange with your above code:

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="date" (ngModelChange)="dateChanged()">
```

Note: you can pass through the change event into the functions using **$event** too.

then in the **dateChanged()** function you can do whatever you need with the new value.